# Is "Spring Data - JPA" the JPA implementation or just extension over another JPA implementation?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm preparing to implement back-end for my app and now I'm projecting data layer. I'm looking towards Spring.

Comment: JPA is a spec, nothing more.  There are many implementations, including Hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data JPA is not JPA implementation. It provides way to build data access layer to the top of underlying JPA. Should you use Spring Data JPA at all depends about your preferences. List of features can be found from [homepage](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa):

> - Sophisticated support to build repositories based on Spring and JPA
> - Support for QueryDSL predicates and thus type-safe JPA queries
> - Transparent auditing of domain class
> - Pagination support, dynamic query execution, ability to integrate custom data access code
> - Validation of @Query annotated queries at bootstrap time
> - Support for XML based entity mapping

This means you need additionally some JPA implementation (for example EclipseLink, Hibernate, etc.).